# Why does gulp render .css and css.maps in .scss directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have spent a bit of time trying to work out why .css and .css.map files are being rendered when running this task.

```
      //list dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
// var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
// var merge = require('merge-stream');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

/*sass watch and compiler */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return  gulp.src('./assets/sass/styles.scss') //simon H change
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});
/*sass compiler */

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src("./assets/js/**/*.js")
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./assets/sass/styles.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./assets/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task("build", ['sass','scripts','watch']);
```

folder structure looks like this before compiled

```
/assets
 --/js
 --/sass
 ----/includes
 ------/components
 --------/_body.scss
 --------/_nav.scss
 --------/_hamburger.scss
 ----/styles.scss
   --/css
```

Then it looks like this once built.

```
    /assets
 --/js
 --/sass
 ----/includes
 ------/components
 --------/_body.css     <-
 --------/_body.css.map <-- new files
 --------/_body.scss
 --------/_nav.scss
 --------/_hamburger.scss
 ----/styles.scss
   --/css
dist/
--/css
----/styles.css
```

Styles.scss Contents

```
@import 'includes/components/_nav';
@import 'includes/components/_hamburger';
@import 'includes/components/_body';
```

Once this compiles it works, however, the css and css.map files are being created in this location when I modify the `_body.scss` file (same as all the other scss files). I don't want _body.css and other files compiled in the assets/sass folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have gulp look for your main sass file and leave it to that to do the importing?

```
return  gulp.src('./assets/sass/styles.scss')
```

Comment: I reviewed and made these changes, I am still getting this problem when changing the gulp.src. I have changed the question to reflect this. Cheers

Comment: If your question has changed you should write a new one so my answer has context :-)

Comment: sorry still learning stackover flow. i added a comment where i changed  the src to your recommended one.